# Save github username for updating submodules azure pipeline

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-pipelines

I am attempting to checkout a submodule within my azure pipeline.

The submodules have been added via:

```
git submodule add <myrepo>
```

and pushed to the main repo.

I now need to get this repo checked out during the pipeline execution which I am doing with the following code:

```
  jobs:
  - job: checkoutSubmodule
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        submodules: true
```

This then results in the following error being thrown:

```
Cloning into '/home/vsts/work/1/s/devops-scripting'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/hkelly999/devops-scripting.git' into submodule path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/devops-scripting' failed
Failed to clone 'devops-scripting'. Retry scheduled
```

How can i configure the pipieline to remember my github username? I have tried

```
git config --global user.name "myusername"
```

However this seems to only work with pushing commits, not when i attempt to update submodules.

How can i either input a username into my pipeline, or get the pipeline to remember my github user?

Answer (score 1):

For private projects the azure devops build VM doesn't have permission to clone your submodules. In order to give it permission to clone you can either add your username and password or add a personal access token(PAT) to the url in the `.gitmodules` file in your repo on Azure devops.

You need to change the url to `https://{yourPAT}@github.com/xxx/yyy.git`

`.gitmodules` file look like:

```
[submodule "DbConnector"]
    path = DbConnector
    url = https://{yourPAT}@github.com/xxx/xxxx
```

Here is a [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/690278/build-pipeline-doesnt-understand-new-domain-url-fo.html) with similar issue and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops#checkout-submodules) you can refer to.